# DHTMLX vs EJS Treegrid vs ExtJS Treegrid

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, grid, dhtmlx

For my project I have a requirement where I have to implemented a complex grid structure. The grid will have some rows with value/sub-value hierarchy which have to be shown like tree structure. I did a POC with SlickGrid but found the grid to be not so comprehensive as commercial alternatives like [DHTMLX](http://www.dhtmlx.com/index.shtml), [EJS Treegrid](http://www.tgantt.com/treegrid/www/Gantt.html) or [ExtJS Treegrid](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/) (as I assessed from online  documentation and samples).

So, I wanted to know if anybody has worked with DHTMLX, EJS Treegrid or EXTJS Treegrid and could guide me how do they stand considering code maintainability, features, events exposed etc...

Any help will be great.

Thanks
Saarthak

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using [EJS Treegrid](http://www.tgantt.com).  It has a rich feature set (you can essentially emulate Microsoft Excel), and has a JSON/XML API which exposes
all the events we've needed.  My only gripes with it is its oddly organized documentation, and lack of a visible user/developer community.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations) discussion about JQuery grids might be helpful.

Cheers!

Comment: now with even more "excel" than ever before, but no improvement on your "gripes". I agree with your gripes. We have full support, too, and its kind of slow and vague via email. We only seem to have problems when we get very, very creative with the features.